# Shortcut for Resolution Change using NVIDIA

Tags: nvidia, shortcut-keys, resolution, screen

Back several ubuntu versions ago I could resize the screen using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> (For higher resolution) OR <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> (For lower resolution).
Now they do not seem to work. How can I add them again for resolution change.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this feature is gone since Bullet Proof X. However:

You can create short cuts (System → Preferences → Keyboard Shortcuts) to change your resolution:

- Have a look at System → Preferences → Monitors to see your available modes, in my case there are four, from 640×480 up to my native resolution
- You can now use `xrandr -s 0` to `xrandr -s 3` to change to one of them.

It's not exactly the same as the old +/– business, but it works rather well.

To add a short cut, in the *Keyboard Shortcut* settings, click *add*, choose a name, like 'First Resolution', a command like `xrandr -s 0`, and hit Apply. Then click the short cut cell, where it says *Disabled* and press, for example, Ctrl+Shift+Alt+0 (my preference).

**Note:** this works on any graphics card, not just NVidia's.

Comment: Actually i can not use System → Preferences → Monitors since it is recommended to use System → Administration → NVIDIA X Server settings. i wil try the rest you mention here and give it a go.

Comment: Yes it works good. At least it gives me the default i like to use when something changes the resolution. Thank you.

Comment: Cool! (I couldn't test it myself unfortunately).