# How to toggle between 2 specific resolutions via keyboard shortcut?

Tags: shortcut-keys, display, display-resolution

I'm using Ubuntu on a laptop (with its built-in screen disabled) connected to a 3840x2160 external display.

Before sharing my screen on a video chat, I always like to switch the resolution down to 1920x1080.

I want to be able to quickly toggle the resolution of my external display between 3840x2160 and 1920x1080 via a keyboard shortcut, such as <kbd>Super</kbd><kbd>PrntScrn</kbd>.

This [really old answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/23077/48214) might be relevant as a starting place, but I'm not sure where to go from here.

As an example (but not on Ubuntu), I was able to do it on a Macbook following [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/387482/53510).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/23077/48214) was more helpful than I originally realized.

1. In Ubuntu 20.04, go to Settings → Displays.
2. In the Resolution dropdown, count the position of the resolution options that you care about. (In the screenshot below, "3840 x 2160" is 1st, and "1920 x 1080" is 7th.)
3. In Terminal, `xrandr -s 0 -r 30.00` will set the system to use the 1st resolution at 30 Hz (or 29.98 Hz actually, somehow), and `xrandr -s 6 -r 30.00` will switch to the 7th. Test those commands.
4. `vim toggle_resolution.sh` and paste the sample bash script shown below (and edit as necessary).
5. `chmod +x toggle_resolution.sh`
6. Run `./toggle_resolution.sh` a couple times to test the toggling.
7. You could create a hotkey in Settings → Keyboard Shortcuts to run that bash script file.

[image: Settings → Displays]

Sample bash script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# https://askubuntu.com/a/1351112/48214
X=$(xrandr --current | grep '*' | uniq | awk '{print $1}' | cut -d 'x' -f1)
# echo "$X"

if [ $X == 3840 ]
then
        xrandr -s 6 -r 30.00
else
        xrandr -s 0 -r 30.00
fi
```

Comment: Nice. Do you know why the max refresh rate is not selected by default?

Comment: @RudyVissers No